# Convert List Of XML Tags in varchar column to comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table that contains a list of xml tags/values that I need to use to join to another table to retrieve their actual value and display the result as a csv list.

Example varchar data:

```
<choice id="100"/><choice id="101"/><choice id="102"/>
```

However, these values actually translate to other values: red, white, blue respectively. I need to convert that list to the following list:

```
red,white,blue
```

As a recap, the "source" table column is varchar, and contains a list of xml attribute values, and those values translate to other values by joining to another table.  So the other table has a primary key of id (int) with rows for 100,101,102.  Each of those rows has values red,white,blue respectively.  I hope this makes enough sense.

Here is the ddl to set up the scenario:

```
create table datatable(
  id int,
  data nvarchar(449)
  primary key (id)
);

insert into datatable(id, data)
values(1,'<choice id="100"/><choice id="101"/><choice id="102"/>')
    ,(2,'<choice id="100"/>')
    ,(3,'<choice id="101"/>')
    ,(4,'<choice id="102"/>');

create table choicetable(
    id int,
    choicevalue nvarchar(449)
    primary key (id)
);

insert into choicetable(id, choicevalue)
values(100,'red')
    ,(101,'white')
    ,(102,'blue');
```

This would be the first time I've tried parsing XML in this manner so I'm a little stumped where to start.  Also, I do not have control over the database I am retrieving the data from (3rd party software).

Comment: What have you tried so far that's not working? You haven't supplied any related sample data for anyone to propose a working query.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Whenever a single row of a single column contains a list, someone has made a truly horrible mistake in their schema design.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback.  I guess I need to edit the above post to include the additional information people are requesting.  Not finding an edit button for the main post.  I will try using my own reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without proper sample data it's hard to give an exact query. But you would do something like this

- Use `CROSS APPLY` to convert the `varchar` to `xml`
- Use `.nodes` to shred the XML into separate rows.
- Join using `.value` to get the `id` attribute
- Group up, and concatenate using `STRING_AGG`. You may not need `GROUP BY` depending on your situation.

```sql
SELECT
  xt.Id,
  STRING_AGG(ot.Value, ',')
FROM XmlTable xt
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(xt.XmlColumn AS xml) ) v(XmlData)
CROSS APPLY v.XmlData.nodes('/choice') x1(choice)
JOIN OtherTable ot ON ot.Id = x1.choice.value('@id','int')
GROUP BY
  xt.Id;
```

I would advise you to store XML data in an `xml` typed column if at all possible.

Comment: I do not have enough points to upvote this.  Sorry.